# Pattern Match on Coproduct?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given the following from the [Shapeless Guide](http://underscore.io/books/shapeless-guide/):

```
import shapeless.{Coproduct, :+:, CNil, Inl, Inr}

case class Red()
case class Amber()
case class Green()
type Light = Red :+: Amber :+: Green :+: CNil
```

I tried to pattern match on `Light`:

```
scala> def f(l: Light) = l match {
     |   case Red(_) => 42
     |   case _      => 66
     | }
<console>:21: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : Red
 required: shapeless.:+:[Red,shapeless.:+:[Amber,shapeless.:+:[Green,shapeless.CNil]]]
         case Red(_) => 42
              ^
```

But, that failed. How can I pattern match on `Light`?

Comment: `case Inl(Red()) =>`

Comment: def f(l: Light) = l match {
       case Inl(Red()) => 0
       case Inr(Inl(Amber())) => 1
       case Inr(Inr(Inl(Green()))) => 2
       case _ => 3
    }